# Background image color detection with Android Paint

Tags: android, paint, android-drawable

When I start painting , it colors the whole background , I mean it should only paint the white spots.
Application screenshot is as follows.
Using Android Paint ,I want to paint only white spots on background-drawable[Panda] and skip any other color.

`onDraw()` function is:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);

    for (Pair<Path,Integer> path_clr : path_color_list ){
        paint.setColor(path_clr.second);
        canvas.drawPath( path_clr.first, paint);
    }

    for (Pair<Path,Integer> path_clr : circular_path_color_list ){
        circlePaint.setColor(path_clr.second);
        canvas.drawPath( path_clr.first, paint);
    }
}
```

and `onTouchEvent` function is:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    float pointX = event.getX();
    float pointY = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        circlePath.reset();
        path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);

        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
        circlePath.reset();
        circlePath.addCircle(pointX, pointY, 10, Path.Direction.CW);

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        circlePath.reset();

        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }

    postInvalidate();
    return true;
}
```

[image: Color Activity]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thing you're describing is called masking. You need a mask (white areas) and a masked image (your strokes). When drawing, you have to use the mask to cut your strokes to a shape of the mask. It can be done using PorterDuff modes. See the pseudocode:

```
Bitmap panda;
Bitmap whiteAreas;
Bitmap strokes;
Canvas strokesCanvas;
Paint paint;

private void init() {
    strokesCanvas = new Canvas(strokes);
    paint = new Paint();
}

private void addStroke(Path stroke){
    paint.setXfermode(null);
    strokesCanvas.drawPath(stroke,paint);
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    strokesCanvas.drawBitmap(whiteAreas,0,0,paint);
    paint.setXfermode(null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(panda,0,0,paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(strokes,0,0,paint);
}
```

See the link for more info: http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html

---

EDIT: Here's an image how it works. Blue areas should be transparent. Multiplication between the mask and the strokes is what's called masking.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but i don't have any knowledge about bitmap masking. What value would `Bitmap whiteAreas` be initialized with! same is the problem with `Bitmap strokes`

Comment: whiteAreas is just what the name says - a bitmap as large as the panda image, with transparent background and with the belly and the face of the panda drawn.
strokes bitmap is used to hold the drawings done by a user.
I've prepared an image for You

Comment: Sorry again , but I am not getting the point :( , I mean how would I create mask and strokes bitmaps from `view` class? The background , we are painting over , is a class extended from `view`.

Comment: The mask is a separate png file with colorable areas drawn by an artist. The strokes bitmap is just a bitmap allocated by the view to hold the strokes.